# Embedded PDF is refreshing on key down

Tags: html, angular

I'm using the `<embed>` tag to show PDF files on my Angular 7 application.

This is the code:

```
<embed *ngIf="mediaElement == 'embedPdf'" [src]="cleanUrl(contentUri)" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px" />
```

Function `cleanUrl()`:

```
cleanUrl(url: string): SafeResourceUrl {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
}
```

It works, but when I press any key it cause the embed to refresh:

[image]

There are no key event detection on my code.

I tried to use `<object>` instead of `<embed>`. The `<object>` works fine with no refresh on key press, but sometimes the PDF isn't loaded.

I tried to use an `<iframe>` too but it has the same behavior of `<embed>` tag.

Comment: You may want to implement a loader so it doesn't appear to flash.

Comment: Could you give me some details about this loader please?

Comment: Can you share the functions your using to update the PDF currently? I see your `cleanUrl` function but it doesn't fully explain the PDF updating.

Comment: @BrandonKiefer thanks to try to help me. I'm using Angular Material Dialog and I think it can be the problem. I'll need to use another dialog plugin. I put it outside the dialog and it worked

Comment: So you don't need any help with this? Glad you got it taken care of!